# Why doesn't the Magnum repository show the packages in CentOS 6?

Tags: perl, centos, repository, cpan, yum

I'm trying to install the Net::Amazon::S3 library but CPAN is failing to build it.

I found the Magnum repository at http://rpm.mag-sol.com/Centos/6/x86_64/ which includes the library in a package. Unfortunately after adding the repository to Yum, I can't install any of the packages.

If I run the command `yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="magnum" list available` I see none of the packages on the list.

How can I install the required packages through Yum?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds strange. I've just run exactly the same command on my Centos 6.4 x86_64 box and I got a list of over 300 available packages.

Have you tried running "yum clean all" before the "yum list available" command?

Dave...
[Magnum Solutions RPM Repository Admin]